# Updating onEachFeature property of GeoJSON in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

Here's my code:

```
var eurojson = L.geoJSON(
eurojson,{
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
  style: EU_color
});

var econjson = eurojson;
econjson.setStyle(Econ);
```

When I initialize `econjson` variable, I would like the `onEachFeature` property to be null, or turned off (I still don't  have the vocabulary down yet). But I still need it for the `eurojson` variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply construct a new L.GeoJSON with different options. You can simply leave out the `onEachFeature` part for the `econjson`:

```
var eurojson = L.geoJSON(data,{
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    style: EU_color
})

var econjson = L.geoJSON(data,{
    style: Econ
})
```